# Notifications for call information and trigger SMS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I would like to know the possibilities on implementing the below things

1) when i making a outgoing call if the person doesn't accept the call, i want to send sms / mail to that person from my application(manually / automatically).

2) If i reject the incoming call ( i mean when i get missed call), i want to send sms / Mail to that person from my application((manually / automatically).

3) Can we able to receive the call related information / notifications to my application

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

1. Can't do this without being a jailbroken app
2. Can't do this without being a jailbroken app
3. No, not without being a jailbroken app

Unfortunately, even though this may be useful in many ways, Apple restricts its developers from having access to such things as being notified of when a user doesn't accept a call or if the user tried to call a person and failed. For it to be slightly possible, your user would have to have your application continuously running in background (so they would of had to start it before making/denying said call). And then the notifications would have to be sent to your application.

Now, its impossibility dies when you create a jailbroken app, which is essentially being run as root, can live forever, and can continuously run in background. You could then get all the information you required, but it would be a very large effort, especially if you are not used to that type of development and even then you would no be able to get on Apple's app store.

Answer (score 1):

Using the current iOS SDK, the only way your app can capture interruptions is by using `interruptionListenerCallback` callback. but I doubt it will be any useful for you, but you can try.

Basically it let you listen to events, such as alarm activated or phone is ringing event.

It was designed to stop and resume audio playback in your app and it's a part of the `AudioToolbox` framework.

```
void interruptionListenerCallback (
                                   void *inUserData,
                                   UInt32   interruptionState
                                   ) {



    if (interruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {

      NSLog (@"Interrupted. Stopping playback or recording.");
      [_player stopAudio];
      interruptedOnPlayback = YES;


    } else if ((interruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) && interruptedOnPlayback) {
        // if the interruption was removed, and the app had been playing, resume playback

      [_player startAudio];
      interruptedOnPlayback = NO;
    }

}


 // Set the callback in your app delegate
OSStatus mystatus = AudioSessionInitialize (
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL,
                                          interruptionListenerCallback,
                                          self
                                          );
```

As you can see, it's really limited. your app has to be running in the background, and there's no way of you to know what event happened or what the user did.